# How to recognize font type from any text

Tags: java, android, image-processing, fonts

I have an image where some text is written. I need to identify font type of the text. Is it possible? Is there any way to recognize font type from any text.

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo

Comment: do you want to recognize font at Runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Found this: http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/